# How to show In-App-Purchasing system in local currency in a Unity3D game

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, firebase-remote-config

I have a  3D game made in the **unity personal editor**. I have made a system for in-game currency and have also made a system for **In-App-Purchasing**.

But what I worry is that I have the purchase buttons in INR IE Indian Rupee. I have seen many games like subway surfer, that are made abroad, shows these “BUY” buttons with values marked in INR for India but in USD for USA. How do I achieve this? Which tools and technologies can I use?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea that you start making requirements that people who help you for free must do it urgently...

Comment: afaik it’s done automatically from the configuration that is set in the google play console

Comment: The `SKProduct` (iOS) and `SkuDetails` (Android) will contain the localized price that you should display to users. If you're using a purchase framework it should include these for you.